Selenium: 'stale element not found in the current frame' after run execute_script
I want to use selenium change the datepicker value in the frame, so i have to remove readonly attribute firstly. But i get the "selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found in the current frame" exception after I run javascript code by execute_script() function.
driver.get(DATA_ASSERTS)
# switch to iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))
time.sleep(2)
input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div/input[@placeholder="date"]')

# remove input readonly attribute
driver.execute_script(
    'document.getElementsByClassName("ant-calendar-picker-input ant-input")[0].removeAttribute("readonly")', input)
# 
i = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div/input[@placeholder="date"]')
# when run here, report a error
i.clear()

I attempt switch to parent frame then switch to children frame again. but no use.
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))


where is the element located? and why are there 3 difference selectors?
